# How can I make a scatter plot using proplot? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I just downloaded the `ProPlot` package and am wondering how I can make a scatter plot. I looked into [this example](https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#Plotting-stuff), but as I tried

```
import proplot as plt
plt.figure(...)
plt.scatter(...)
```

it returns me `AttributeError: module 'proplot' has no attribute 'scatter'` . My plot worked when I did

```
import proplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(...)
plt.scatter(...)
```

And I did see the effect of `proplot` in this way. However, I don't think it's right to import two packages with the same notation `plt`. Is there a better way I can generate the scatter plot using `proplot`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proplot does not offer a direct replacement for the scatter plot at the top level of the proplot module. The only way to construct it is to call the method of an axis object:

```py
import proplot as pplt
fig, ax = pplt.subplots()
ax.scatter()
```

Or alternatively:

```py
fig = pplt.figure()
ax = fig.subplot()
ax.scatter(...)
```

Note that if you import matplotlib after proplot under the same name `plt` alias, you won't be able to use the proplot interface under `plt` since it'll be replaced by matplotlib. It is not "wrong" to do so, since it is legal python, but surely not what you intended to accomplish.